# Outlook Macro to Add a bit of Text from a Quick Part

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros

Does anyone have a macro that adds a Quick Part text to an email in Outlook?
I have some text stored in a Quick Part but I use it that often that I'd like to have a button on the ribbon to add it directly instead of having to click through the Quick Part menu.

Comment: I think you can create various signatures but only 1 default

Comment: Please note that Super User is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems.

Comment: First of all, signatures don't cut it because I will want a signature as well and the point of the quick part text is that it can go anywhere. Signatures replace each other too.

Comment: I wasn't asking someone to write a script. I just wanted to know if anyone knew of one. I thought this might be a common problem.

Comment: I have since discovered that if you start typing the quick part yourself, Outlook pops up and asks if you want to enter it. Might not really need a script at all.